Craft Cloud, CSS not working
I have setup a new project using craft cloud, locally everything works fine. But on the production site, it gives a  404 error on the stylesheets, and I do not understand why.
This is all I know:

Trying to go directly to the file url does not work either.
Normal images (uploaded through the cms) works.
Everything works locally
I'm 100% deploying the files (I can see them in my GitHub)


I would probably recommend contacting P&T support for help with this.

Most likely, you need to account for artifacts/artifact URLs: https://craftcms.com/knowledge-base/cloud-builds#artifact-urls
But if that’s not it, hit us up at support@craft.cloud, and we'll figure it out!

"I'm 100% deploying the files (I can see them in my GitHub)" – it sounds like that means you're not building these in our node pipeline, which is fine. However, as Brad mentioned, you still need to use the cloud.artifactUrl() template functions to render these URLS.
Even though they're part of your repo, Craft Cloud, by design, will only serve Craft requests from your main domain. Static assets will be routed through the CDN, and thus need to be referenced via the cloud.artifactUrl() tag.

FWIW, Removing this restriction is on our roadmap, which would allow things to work without template changes: https://github.com/craftcms/cloud/discussions/9
